# Notification in web application when a database is updated

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, notifications

i am trying to develop a web application, which should show a notification ( similar to facebook notifications) whenever there is an update in a database.
Could someone please help me with the notifications part? are there any third party tools/plugins which can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide us with some of your code.

Comment: I am still doing background research... I am confused between using python / jsp. Any suggestions regarding which of them to use to make my life easier? :p

Answer (score 0):

First of all what kind of technologies are you using? (Backend and FrontEnd)

In a general way you need 2 things:

1. Backend after a DB update sends notifications through Websockets to notify all clients.
2. Clients subscribes the notifications and when receives a notification, then updates the UI.